# Crosstool-ng 1.19.0, make error with eglibc

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I'm currently trying to build crosstool-ng for my raspberry pi cross-compilation but I'm running into some issues. I'm getting the following error while trying to build crosstool version 1.19.0:

```
[CFG  ]    checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc    
[CFG  ]    checking version of arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc    ... 4.8.2, ok
[CFG  ]    checking for gnumake... no
[CFG  ]    checking for gmake... no
[CFG  ]    checking for make... make
[CFG  ]    checking version of make... 4.0, bad
[CFG  ]    checking for gnumsgfmt... no
[CFG  ]    checking for gmsgfmt... no
[CFG  ]    checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
[CFG  ]    checking version of msgfmt... 0.19.1, ok
[CFG  ]    checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
[CFG  ]    checking version of makeinfo... 5.2, ok
[CFG  ]    checking for sed... sed
[CFG  ]    checking version of sed... 4.2.2, ok
[CFG  ]    checking for gawk... gawk
[CFG  ]    checking version of gawk... 4.1.1, ok
[CFG  ]    checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-nm... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-nm
[CFG  ]    checking for autoconf... autoconf
[CFG  ]    checking whether autoconf works... no
[ERROR]    configure: error: 
[CFG  ]    *** These critical programs are missing or too old: make
[CFG  ]    *** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing C library headers & start files'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@257]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_backend_once[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@347]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_backend[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@143]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_start_files[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@60]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@632]
```

According to this website: http://colocsbar.blogspot.fr/2014/01/crosstool-ng-1190-et-make-40.html
I have to patch the eglibc configure script. But I can't find which one it is, I tried to patch every glibc script I could find into the crosstool folder but the patching failed every time.
Does anyone have a solution to get rid ofthis error? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is kind of late, but I ran into the same problem and information is sparse. It appears to be a shortsighted version limit in eglibc. The `INSTALL` file says 3.79 or newer, but the actual config checks against 3.79 and 3.89 (I think, not sure about pattern matching syntax used) and fails otherwise. There is a .patch file available on that link, but I couldn't find the information about what file it was either.

So I grep'd the entire directory for `ac_prog_version=` which gave a bunch of hits but the configure for eglibc was there.

The file I changed was: `.build/src/eglibc-2_13/configure`

It's around line ~5000; depends on your versions. I changed it to 4.1 since that's my make version (the patch does 4.0--although it should really make it 3.79 or newer like the `INSTALL` file says).

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to point out that eglibc is not longer developed and it is recommended that you use glibc instead. I ran into issues related to eglibc while trying to build a toolchain for Raspberry Pi. eglibc may be removed from crosstools-ng soon. Please see this issue: https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/8.